# Alternative to synchronous REST communication betweeen microservices

Tags: architecture, microservices, api-design

I know synchronous communication between services is an anti-pattern, so I'm searching for a good solution for my use-case.

I have this two services:

- `Location Service` that manages users location
- `Score Service` that manages users score

Now, I have to build another service: `Users Feed Service` (UFS). It has to return users near to a given location, ordered by score (descending).

**Synchronous solution**

1. Given a location, UFS fetch nearby users from the location service (REST)
2. For each one of them, it gets her score from the Score Service (REST)
3. Finally, it sorts the users in memory and return them

What is the alternative? I have been thinking about something like this:

**Event queue solution**

- UFS stores users locations and scores in a database, or memory cache or something
- It listens to changes in a queue to update its data when the score service and location service publish in it

This way, when client request the users feed, the users feed service don't have to perform any network request (it owns the necessary data)

Is this a good solution? How can I improve it? Will it scale in a large amount of users?

Comment: It will scale better than the synchronous solution. Queues are better and handling high volume than APIs. However, you have to offset that against the complexity of queued transport infrastructure. Are you sure you're not optimizing prematurely?

Comment: Maybe I am. I'm afraid of the future changes though. A migration from synchronous to queue based system can be hard. Anyway, I think you are right. Maybe I'm trying to solve inexistent scalability issues. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have some additional requirements you're not listing but it seems to me that in this case an event based solution that would replicate lots of data from other services is way-way over engineering.

If the UFS gets location when there are changes in the location service-  then it makes sense to  tie its invocation to an event coming from the location service on changes in locations

In regard to the scores service, I'd leave that synchronous but make its interface accept a list of customers rather than making it an n "get customer score" calls to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I deal with a large amount of users? Should I divide it in several calls against score service?

Comment: Depends on what's large? You can change the score service API so that it would accept the list of clients and returns the X clients with highest scores - (TOP n of m) then you'd have to transfer much less data back and forth